# new gcloud firestore scheduler backup does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

i have a firestore and im trying to create schedule backup:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/backups

I created a schedule backup as follows

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules create --project=projectName --database='(default)' --recurrence=daily --retention=2d
```

when i run this :

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules list --database='(default)'
```

i m getting:

```
createTime: '2023-11-13T09:05:18.352661Z'
dailyRecurrence: {}
name: projects/project-name/databases/(default)/backupSchedules/id
retention: 172800s
updateTime: '2023-11-13T09:05:18.352661Z'
```

but when i run  `gcloud alpha firestore backups list`

i m getting 0 items

whats wrong ? i ran this backup more than 12 hours ago

where do i see the status ? in which bucket it has been saved?